# What should I learn along with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a complete programming beginner. I know a little HTML and the only CSS I know is using a change element tool like Stylebot. Obviously I don't want to be overwhelmed, but I'd like to be able to develop websites, or at the very least, throw up some MVP's.

What should I learn along with RoR? If you can, list them in order of importance starting with the most mandatory.

Comment: Do you want to do just web dev, or do u also want to code native apps and games from time to time?

Comment: My primary objective, as an entrepreneur, is to be able to understand the technology, speak the language, and occasionally work on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've seen just about every Rails tutorial there is (at least the most well known).

My favorite is the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

The best part is, it's **free** - as in beer.  But it's also very thorough.  I've gone through it at least twice to get concepts that I had a hard time with the first time around.

As you go through it, you'll learn Ruby concepts, Rails concepts, and a little CSS and Javascript.

I think Rails is a good choice - it was the first framework I ever picked up, and when you go to other MVC frameworks you will carry over the good habits you learned from Rails.

As far as other things to learn, well it depends on what you want to do.  If you want to stick with web development, than you definitely need to learn:

- **HTML5** - I think this goes without saying - but be sure to check out Haml as well at some point
- **CSS** - learn the basics first, then take a look at Sass and Less
- **Javascript** - most people would agree that JQuery is the predominant framework for basic Javascript work right now
  (manipulating the DOM).  But you'll also find people who are fans of
  MooTools and Dojo (as well as a lot of others I'm sure).
- **Javascript Frameworks** - JS can quickly turn into a mess if you have a project that is making heavy use of it.  My favorite
  Javascript framework is Backbone.js.  There are also others that are
  good like - Spine.js, Knockout.js, SproutCore, etc, etc...  (there's
  lots of them)
- **Version Control** - I really can't stress enough how important this is.  Git version control will help you create branches of code so just in case you screw something up, you can just delete the branch and start over without destroying your whole project (it's saved my butt a few times).  It will also allow you to work with others on your projects.  Start a GitHub account and start storing your code there.  The RailsTutorial that I linked to above will get you started with that too.

Hopefully that's enough buzzwords to get you on the right track.  If you are just beginning than a lot of this stuff can seem overwhelming, but try to focus on the basics of programming itself for a little while and the rest of it will come together as you go.

Another online book that I am a big fan of is ["Learn Ruby the Hard Way"](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/).  Don't let the name fool you - it's not a difficult book to get through.  But it teaches you basic programming skills the old fashioned way - by actually typing out the examples and giving you problems to work through.  Well worth taking a look at.

Comment: Yes, I've been working through a ton of tutorials, I can confirm there are a bunch out there. I'm planning to work through Hartl's tutorial next. Would RoR, with basic HTML/CSS/Javascript be sufficient enough to throw up a nice looking website? 

Are there templates that work well with RoR?

Comment: You can go a long, long way with Rails, html, css, and javascript.  The only thing that would limit you is your skill level.  As far as design frameworks go, you should check into Twitter Bootstrap.  There are gems that will integrate it with Rails as well.  Check out Ryan Bate's RailsCasts website - he will definitely get you started on that as well as other things.  You can also use templates such as Wordpress templates - but you'd just have to swap out the php code with Ruby code.  I'd stick with basics first, then try your hand at templates later.

Comment: Thank you. I'm bookmarking this thread for future reference.

Comment: Hi, the first link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Well, start with Ruby. as @Amit has said. Next, try some mainstream .NET language (I recommend C#), they're pretty mature and are good enough to hire you in most tech companies (even SO). It's also good for desktop development with WPF, Windows Forms, GTK# etc. And for Game Dev, with the XNA Game Framework, OpenTK and SFML .NET. You can even program for embedded systems and Windows Phone. Hence it's like killing 5 (or more) birds with one stone.

Learning a functional language like Haskell along the way might also help you. It can become a trump card on your CV and mature your skills as a Software Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're really looking for two things: a sense of what to learn, and then where to learn it.

If you want make websites, you're on the right track. Learn HTML, CSS, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and JQuery.

**HTML and CSS** — HTML and CSS can be gleaned from tutorial websites, such as http://net.tutsplus.com/, but the "Head First" series of books (http://headfirstlabs.com/) are a non-threatening option for a beginner. For great discussions of how others have done things elegantly with CSS, check out "A List Apart" at http://www.alistapart.com/

**Ruby** — A beginning text to get you going with Ruby is Chris Pine's "Learn to Program." It won't help you directly with making webpages, but it will get you thinking in Ruby, the language that underpins Ruby on Rails.

**RoR** — If you are looking to dive into Ruby on Rails, you will need books to take you the distance. Most books, however, quickly go out of date, so you will need to check what version of Ruby on Rails the book covers. The most thorough hand-holding guide is Michael Hartl's book, freely available at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book (no need to order the PDF). It is very complete and can indeed seem overwhelming, but the author goes in depth with the examples. There is also a book from the founders and contributors of Ruby on Rails, called "Agile Web Development with Rails," which can be confusing for a beginner, but works well if you supplement it with online tutorials.

**JQuery** — Eventually, you'll want to branch out into JQuery, which will be the easiest way to get into Javascript, allowing you to manipulate things on the page after it's done loading (responding to user interaction). And JQuery has incredible documentation on its own site: http://jquery.com/

**etc.** — And you'll notice that people who use Ruby on Rails also use things like "SASS," which modify the way CSS works. Once you're comfortable with the basics, it can be fun and useful to experiment with these things.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Ah, PhilippKregg mentions the most important of all: [Rails Casts](http://railscasts.com). That got me through more jams than anything other single resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a basic course on Ruby. A good tutorial IMHO is at net.tutsplus.com/sessions/ruby-for-newbies/